# SQL Error 26 Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection-string, iis-8

I'm trying to find out this problem the whole day. I get an error on a website I'm trying to publish :

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I have done everything that other threads have said. Like open firewall ports (To make my life easy i just disabled it) Set up TCP/IP in SQL Server Configuration Manager, also done that set it to 1433. Yet there is something weird there just to say maybe that is it but im not sure on each IP it says Enabled: No

Just thought that was weird but yea. And yes restarted SQL server service like 20 times now. My instance name is `SQLSERVER2016` I don't know if that was a smart idea.

I think it's the connection string since in SSMS I can connect to the instance without a problem but I'm not sure I'm still very new to SQL. I've set everything to connect with the Administrator account. So here are my connection strings.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=KEVIN-WEBSERVER\SQLSERVER2016;Initial Catalog=BetaUsersDatabase;Trusted_Connection=yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="ForumDatabase" 
     connectionString="Data Source=KEVIN-WEBSERVER\SQLSERVER2016;Initial Catalog=BetaForumDatabase;Trusted_Connection=yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I've also tried some other variations but they all did not work I have not kept them sorry. But yes, I'm using SQL Server 2016 Express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a **named instance**, KEVIN-WEBSERVER\SQLSERVER2016, and the named instance by default is listening on some dynamic port, that of course is not 1433.

In order to connect to a named instance you should provide IP,port or you can use SQL Server Browser and pass in your instance name.

Your connection string does the latter, i.e. you pass in only the instance name, so your SQL Server Browser must be started.

Here [Overview of the SQL Server Browser service](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1946/overview-of-the-sql-server-browser-service/) you find more about SQL Server Browser

Comment: So except form KEVIN-WEBSERVER i do this IPaddress,1433\SQLSERVER2016? And that still does not explance why i can log in like that to SSMS and it works but when i use it in a connection string it fails

Comment: Okay it worked putting the IP and port there but can you please tell me why i needed to put that there its a fresh install of everything. why is there so much configuration required?

Comment: If your 1433 port works, you did something strange when configurating your instance. 1433 is reserved for **default** instance, now if someone decides to install a default instance it will fail

Comment: If you really use 1433, it will be enough to pass in the computer name only, like this: Data Source=KEVIN-WEBSERVER, and you still will be able to connect

Comment: Okay so i still need to learn a lot about this thanks very much.

Comment: >>>And that still does not explance why i can log in like that to SSMS<<< maybe you was connecting via SSMS **locally**, i.e. from the same pc. In this case there is no need to know the port because it's Shared memory that is used as a network protocol, not TCP\IP. When instead you try to connect from another pc, Shared memory just cannot be used, so it's not enough to know instance name, you need a port. And you have 2 options here: to pass the correct port in your connection string or to start SQL Server Browser (see the link above) and pass in the instance name

Comment: Yea but the website is also hosted on that same server

Comment: Use select *
from sys.dm_exec_connections to see net_transport in both cases, I'm sure you are using Shared memory in case of SSMS and TCP\IP in the second case

Comment: I think your right i need to do whey more research.

Comment: Or you can force use of tcp\ip via ssms even from the same pc like this: tcp:KEVIN-WEBSERVER\SQLSERVER2016, try this and I think it will failed because your SQL Server Browser is stopped

Comment: ok, study / do your research, fell free to ask me anything. Do not forget to try to launch SQL Server Browser, you'll see it will help you to connect without specifying the port!